Implementing Centralized Authentication with JWT in Django Tenants
I'm developing a Django project that utilizes Django tenants for multi-tenancy management. I have implemented JWT authentication using rest_framework_simplejwt for user authentication. Now, I'm looking to centralize authentication across all tenants.
I want to implement a single sign-on (SSO) solution where users can authenticate once and access all tenant resources without needing to log in separately for each tenant. However, I'm facing challenges integrating this with Django tenants and ensuring secure authentication.
Current Setup:
Here's an overview of my current setup:

Django version: [5.0.4]

Django tenants version: [3.6.1]

Installed packages related to authentication: [simple jwt]


Desired Solution:
I'm seeking guidance on how to implement centralized authentication using JWT in Django tenants. Specifically, I want to:

Understand the best practices for implementing SSO with Django tenants.

Determine how to modify my existing JWT authentication setup to support SSO.

Ensure that authentication is secure and user sessions are managed appropriately across tenants.


Additional Information:

Are there any potential security concerns I should be aware of?

Are there any limitations or challenges with integrating SSO in Django tenants that I should consider?


Any advice, code examples, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
